# Cypress Angular : CypressError “Timed out retrying: Expected to find content” after upgrading angular6 to angular10

Tags: cypress, angular10, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Cypress Angular: CypressError “Timed out retrying: Expected to find content” after upgrading angular6 to angular10

Comment: Please add the code that you tried?

Comment: public validatePdfExportDigitalOptionIsChecked(option: string, isChecked: boolean = true): void {
    cy.get(DigitalColumnsElements.digitalPdfOptions)
      .wait(1000)
      .contains(option)
      .parent()
      .should(isChecked ? 'have.class' : 'not.have.class', 'mat-radio-checked');
  }

Comment: getting same for all test cases

Comment: I think you would need to provide some more details. What is passed as "option" to the function "validatePdfExportDigitalOptionIsChecked" of your test code? As I can see from your provided function you try to test an Angular Material Radio button, maybe the way the radio button works changed. It would be very helpful to see parts of the source code you execute the tests on.